# Is there a way to make a sine wave equal to $0$ everywhere but around its peak? (Sieve of Eratosthenes in wave form)

Tags: prime-numbers, wave-equation

[Editor's comment] The sieve part of the title is from me. The comments from the asker revealed that this what they are hoping to build. JL. [/Editor's comment]

So, basically what I need is **something like this**:

[image: The function is 500^(cos(2pi*x/2))/500]

You can see fairly regular peaks and the function seems to be 0 elsewhere, but it's not. It's just quite small.

What I need is a function that:

- Is **greater than 0 where its peak is** (even a bit around it is ok)
- Is **0 where its neighbour numbers are**
  (In the picture shown, I want it to be 0 where 3, 5, 7, 9 etc... are. It can be a bit greater than 0 where 2.95 or 3.05 is, I don't care. It just needs to be 0 where 3 is, and the other numbers are).

[image: **Other example** (This is 500^(cos(2pi*x/3))/500)]

Here you can see peake where 3, 6, 9 etc... are, but I need the function to be **exactly 0 where 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, etc... are**. I don't care how it behaves in between the numbers, as long as it's 0 where those numbers are and greater than 0 (preferably =1) elsewhere.

One more thing:

- It needs to be a **single equation** and **not a split one**.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:** My goal is to construct an equation that finds prime numbers by looking at the zeroes in this function.

[image: stacked wave]

This has been obtained by 'stacking' the cosine wave functions for multiples of 2, 3, 5 and 7. You can see quite easily that 11 and 13 are marked as 0, but since the function is not exactly 0, but a bit above it when the numbers are possible primes, the error builds up and the function is not reliable anymore after we stack too many of them.

The one in the last picture was this:

999999999999^(cos(2pi*x/2))/999999999999+999999999999^(cos(2pi*x/3))/999999999999+999999999999^(cos(2pi*x/5))/999999999999+999999999999^(cos(2pi*x/7))/999999999999

It is just a sloppy approximation, but shows the concept quite well I guess.

Comment: What is a single equation opposed to a split one and why is that an important condition? Also, it's worth noting that the thing you are describing is not a sine wave, considering the way your function approaches its zeros.

Comment: @Roland: Regarding your second comment, it doesn't look to unreasonable if you are thinking of $(1 + \sin(x))/2$ rather than $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Also, which kind of differentiability do yo need? If continuity is not an issue, then $\chi_{\{2 \mathbb N\}}$ would work.

Comment: I'm going to second @Roland's comment. I assume by "split" the OP means  a piecewise-defined function, but I don't think I've *ever* seen anyone insist on avoiding a formula involving a piece-wise definition actually have a good reason for limiting themselves. The OP really should give a good reason why such a thing needs to be avoided!

Comment: @Andrea: This question does not appear to have anything to do with prime numbers or with the wave equation; you should choose a tag that *actually* describes your question.

Comment: The use of the tag [tag:prime-numbers] has not been explained yet. I get the impression that, given a prime number $p$, you want a function $f(x)$ that A) has period $p$, B) $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$, C) $f(n)=1$ whenever $n$ is a integer multiple of $p$, and D) $f(n)=0$ when $n$ is an integer that is not a multiple of $p$. At least this impression fits your two plots assuming they are what it should look like with $p=2$ and $p=3$ respectively.

Comment: Anyway, Fourier series/polynomials are your friends here. When $p=2$ you can try 
$$f(x)=\cos^{2k}(\pi x/2).$$ Here $k$ is a positive integer, the larger the narrower the spikes, and the flatter the "near zero" range. When $p=3$ you can take advantage of the fact that $\cos(2\pi n/3$ takes value $1$ when $3\mid n$ and value $-1/2$ when $3\nmid n$. Suggesting
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3^{2k}}\left(2\cos(2\pi x/3)+1\right)^{2k}$$ for some positive integer $k$, the higher the "better". With $p>3$ we need more terms. Please comment, whether this is at all what you had in mind.

Comment: @Roland I need to sum different 'wave equations', and it would be easier for me to work out the zeros for a single equation rather than a piecewise one.

Comment: @hurkyl I want to 'stack' waves on top of one another so that the zeroes of the single line equation are prime numbers. This should give me a way to generate primes, add them to the function and find the next one, and so on.  It would also be easy to check if a number is prime by testing if it is a zero of this function or not

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I want to 'stack' waves on top of one another so that the zeroes of the single line equation are prime numbers. (You can look above for the complete answer)

Comment: It looks like the two pictures you have only show that $\cos(2\pi x/2)$ and $\cos(2\pi x/3)$ terms - not the sum. No wonder we didn't get the stacking idea. So, you are trying to build something like [the Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in wave form?

Comment: Have a look at this wiki article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that's exactly what I want to do. I apologise if my idea was not clear from the beginning. I attached an additional picture at the end!

Answer (score 1):

How about $\cos(\pi x/2)^{2n} $ for $n \in \{1,2,3,...\}$? One for even numbers, zero for odd numbers.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I tweaked it a bit and although it' not perfect it is very close to what I'm looking for.
For example, if you plot the following you'll get a rough idea of what I'm aiming at. I just reached 13, but it immediately finds the next prime k. Then you plug it in the sequence as cos(pix/k)^9998 and look for the next one, and so on.

cos(pi*x/2)^(9998)+cos(pi*x/3)^(9998)+cos(pi*x/5)^(9998)+cos(pi*x/7)^(9998)+cos(pi*x/11)^(9998)+cos(pi*x/13)^(9998)

Answer (score 1):

**Sieve of Erathostenes in wave form**

Since this is your actual aim, then I am recasting my answer in a different way.

*Product form*

Take a function $u(x)$, having in every $x=n \in \mathbb N$ a zero of order $q$.
Then the products
$$
P_{\,1,\,n} \left( {u(x)} \right) = \prod\limits_{k\, = \,1}^n {\,u\,(x/k)} \quad P_{\,2,\,n} \left( {u(x)} \right) = \prod\limits_{k\, = \,2}^n {\,u\,(x/k)}  = {{P_{\,1,\,n} \left( {u(x)} \right)} \over {u(x)}}
$$
will have in $x=m \; | m\le n \in \mathbb N$ , respectively,  a zero of order $q \sigma_0(m)$ and $(q-1) \sigma_0(m)$.
If we take another function $v(x)$ (even the same $u(x)$), also with zeros of order $q$ for $x$ being a natural integer, and divide $P_1$ by the square of it,
then the resulting function will have no zero when $x= \text{prime}$, and instead will be null only for composite integral $x$.
So, it has a complementary behaviour vs. the one you are looking for.

For instance
$$
\eqalign{
  & Q_{\,n} \left( {\sin ,\sin } \right) = {1 \over {\sin ^{\,2} \,(\pi x)}}\prod\limits_{k\, = \,1}^n {\,\sin \,(\pi x/k)}  = {1 \over {\sin \,(\pi x)}}\prod\limits_{k\, = \,2}^n {\,\sin \,(\pi x/k)}   \cr 
  & Q_{\,n} \left( {\sin ,{\rm fall}} \right) = {1 \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } } \right)^{\,2} }}\prod\limits_{k\, = \,1}^n {\,\sin \,(\pi x/k)}  = \prod\limits_{k\, = \,1}^n {{{\,\sin \,(\pi x/k)} \over {\left( {x - k} \right)^{\,2} }}}  \cr} 
$$
etc.
Then, it is always possible to multiply by an entire function to change the "envelopping" of the function.

*Sum form*

It is known [(see e.g. this Wolfram site page)](http://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/DivisorSigma/06/01/)
that the number of divisors of $n$ can be written as
$$
\sigma _{\,0} (n) = \sum\limits_{\matrix{
   {1\, \le \,j\, \le \,k}  \cr 
   {1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n}  \cr 
 } } {{1 \over k}\cos \left( {{{2\,\pi j\,n} \over k}} \right)} 
$$
but given the nature of this formula, we also can write
$$
\sigma _{\,0} (m)\quad \left| {\;2 \le m \le n} \right. = \sum\limits_{\matrix{
   {1\, \le \,j\, \le \,k}  \cr 
   {1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n}  \cr 
 } } {{1 \over k}\cos \left( {{{2\,\pi j\,m} \over k}} \right)} 
$$

Then
$$
\eqalign{
  & s_{\,0} (x,n)\quad \left| {\;2 \le x \le n} \right. = \sum\limits_{\matrix{
   {1\, \le \,j\, \le \,k}  \cr 
   {1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n}  \cr 
 } } {{1 \over k}\cos \left( {{{2\,\pi j\,x} \over k}} \right)}   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{\cos \left( {{{k + 1} \over k}\,\pi \,x} \right)\;\sin \left( {\pi \,x} \right)} \over {k\sin \left( {{{\,\pi \,x} \over k}} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sin \left( {\pi \,x} \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {{{\cos \left( {{{k + 2} \over {k + 1}}\,\pi \,x} \right)\;} \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\sin \left( {{{\,\pi \,x} \over {k + 1}}} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\cos \left( {{{k + 2} \over {k + 1}}\,\pi \,x} \right)\;{{\sin \left( {\pi \,x} \right)/\left( {\pi \,x} \right)} \over {\sin \left( {{{\,\pi \,x} \over {k + 1}}} \right)/\left( {{{\,\pi \,x} \over {k + 1}}} \right)}}}  \cr} 
$$

and $s_0(x,n)-2$ is null for all $x$ prime $\le n$, and not for composite integers. However it is null **also for non-integral values of $x$**.